# Gatling use session.set and feed simultaneously

Tags: session-variables, feed, gatling

If I use `.get("/***/quotes-${endPoint}/quotes?source=rtbp&userid=test&symbol=${pTypeSymbol}${authM}${pEqSymbol}")` then ${pEqSymbol} work but
${pTypeSymbol} will be ${pEqSymbol} **it's incorrect example of get it should be in code below**

```
val getApiKeyScenario = scenario("getApiKey")
    .feed(getApiKeyData)
    .feed(pEqSymbolFeed)
    .feed(pOptionSymbol)
    .feed(pOtherSymbol)
    .exec(session => session
      .set("endPoint", "v1")
      .set("pTypeSymbol", "${pEqSymbol}")
      .set("authM", "&apikey=***********"))
    .exec(http("getApiKeyRequest")
      .get("/******/quotes-${endPoint}/quotes?source=rtbp&userid=test&symbol=${pTypeSymbol}${authM}")
      .check(status.is(200))
      .check(checkIf(doLogResponse) {
        bodyString.saveAs("pResponse")
      })
    )
    .doIf(doLogResponse) {
      logResponse()
    }
```

If I try `.set("pTypeSymbol", pEqSymbolFeed.readRecords.head("pEqSymbol"))` will be loop
If I try `.set("pTypeSymbol", s"${pEqSymbol.isDefined}")` not found: value pEqSymbol
If I try `s"${pEqSymbol}"` not found: value pEqSymbol

I logs now is `GET *******/quotes-v1/quotes?source=rtbp&userid=test&symbol=${pEqSymbol}&apikey=******`
But should be `GET *******/quotes-v1/quotes?source=rtbp&userid=test&symbol="Here my value from feed"&apikey=******`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the [official documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/session/expression_el/):

> This Expression Language only works on String values being passed to Gatling DSL methods. Such Strings are parsed only once, when the Gatling simulation is being instantiated.
>
> For example queryParam("latitude", session => "${latitude}") wouldn’t work because the parameter is not a String, but a function that returns a String.

In your example, you don't need to copy `pEqSymbol` into `pTypeSymbol`, you can directly write:

```scala
.exec(session => session
      .set("endPoint", "v1")
      .set("authM", "&apikey=***********"))
    .exec(http("getApiKeyRequest")
      .get("/******/quotes-${endPoint}/quotes?source=rtbp&userid=test&symbol=${pEqSymbol}${authM}")
      )
    )
```

But if you insist on copying, you have to use the [Session API](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/session/session_api/):

```scala
.set("pTypeSymbol", session("pEqSymbol").as[String])
```